# ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found

Tags: python, glibc

I'm trying to run a Python script over ssh on a distant server on which I do not have sudo rights.

This piece of code display the error specified in the title

```
import dlib
```

After this, I run the following :

```
$ ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu10) 2.23
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

So I supposed I don't have the correct version of GLIBC. I'm not sure what I should do. Should I make dlib use another version of GLIBC, or update GLIBC? I don't have sudo rights, which one would be easiest?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @truvaking, were you able to solve the issue. I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing open3d as user?

```
pip install --user open3d
```